# Loop Through every cell in a range to make sure they are the same length

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a test to make sure that every cell in a range of cells has the same length string inside it. Basically, I want to check if every cell in a defined range has a string length of 1. If every cell is 1, then I will do something to the code, else I will do something else. I'm using an evaluate(sumproduct(length()) construct but I am getting a type mismatch. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Name_Length()

Dim aCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NameStr As String
Dim Namer As Range
Dim NameResult As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Data Input")

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ws.Range("E4:E" & LastRow)
NameResult = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(cell))")
Next cell

If NameResult >= 1 Then
 'Do something'
Else
 MsgBox NameResult
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Name_Length()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim addr As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Data Input")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    addr = "E4:E" & LastRow

    'Note `ws.Evaluate` - otherwise the context used will be the
    '   ActiveSheet, which may not be what you want...
    If ws.Evaluate("SUM(1*(LEN(" & addr & ")=1))=rows(" & addr & ")") Then
        Debug.Print "all length=1"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not all length=1"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues...

- You've passed a variable name referencing a range (`cell`) as an address reference. It is not. `cell.address`, however IS a address reference.
- You've passed a variable name in as part of a string. It needs to be broken out and have its value concatenated into the string.

`NameResult = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(" & cell.address & "))")`

Answer (score 0):

You do need to concatenate it out cell.address into your evaluate function so it looks like what nwhaught said:

```
NameResult = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(" & cell.address & "))")
```

However, what you have may not return what you are wanting because it will only do what you would want if the last cell is greater than or equal to 1 character in length. To correct this, possibly try something like this:

```
Sub Name_Length()

Dim aCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NameStr As String
Dim Namer As Range
Dim NameResult As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Data Input")

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Set cell = ws.Range("E4:E" & LastRow)
NameResult = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(" & cell.address & "))")

If NameResult >= 1 Then
 'Do something'
Else
 MsgBox NameResult
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for a TRUE/FALSE to a single definitive question; *'Do all of the cells in the range contain values that are the same length?'*

If this is the case, then iterating through the values is only right if you store a length value and keep comparing that to all subsequent length values. Also, iterating through all of the cells is going to be slower than a bulk operation.

```
Sub Name_Length()
    Dim aCells As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NameLengthResult As Double
    Dim bAllTheSameLength As Boolean

    With Sheets("Data Input")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set aCells = .Range("E4:E" & LastRow)
        NameLengthResult = CDbl(Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(LEN(" & aCells.Address(external:=True) & "))") / aCells.Count)
        bAllTheSameLength = CBool(Round(NameLengthResult, 14) = Len(aCells.Cells(1, 1).Value2))

        If bAllTheSameLength Then
            MsgBox "They are all the same." & Chr(10) & NameLengthResult & " characters wide"
        Else
            MsgBox "They are NOT all the same."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

That will determine whether all cells contain the same number of characters. Be particularly careful with dates as the worksheet [LEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56) will return *5* as the length of a current date (today is *42191*).

If all cells in the range contain values with the same number of characters, you can then use either *NameLengthResult* or the length of any cell in the range to determine the actual length.